# SwiftUI: Cannot convert value of type 'Self' to expected argument type 'Binding<C>'

Tags: swiftui

I was trying to write a protocol to layout cell views for a collection of items, but got the following error:

- `⛔ Cannot convert value of type 'Self' to expected argument type 'Binding<C>'`

```
import SwiftUI

// my protocol for laying out subviews
protocol Layout {
    
    // associated types
    associatedtype Item: Identifiable    // item data
    associatedtype ItemView: View        // item view (cell)
    
    // requirements
    func cellSize(for item: Item) -> CGSize                 // cell size
    func cellCenter(for item: Item) -> CGPoint              // cell position
    @ViewBuilder func cellView(for item: Item) -> ItemView  // cell view for item
}

// an extension that I wish I could use the following syntax:
// `items.layoutCells(with: layout)`
extension RandomAccessCollection where Element: Identifiable
{
    @ViewBuilder func layoutCells<L: Layout>(with layout: L) -> some View {
        ForEach(self) { item in                     // ⛔ this is where the error occurs.
            let size = layout.cellSize(for: item)
            layout.cellView(for: item)
                .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                .position(layout.cellCenter(for: item))
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that SwiftUI is trying to use the [`init<C>(_ data: Binding<C>, content: ...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:content:)-96gx9) initializer to initialize my `ForEach` instance instead of using [`init(_ data: Data, content: ...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:content:)-6oy5i), which I thought SwiftUI would use.

What shoud I do next to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the critical constraint in the middle.

```swift
  @ViewBuilder func layoutCells<L: Layout>(with layout: L) -> some View
  where Element == L.Item {
    ForEach(self) { item in
```

Given that, the `where Element: Identifiable` above may be redundant.